# How to implement Adwords window.google_trackConversion() in Gtagjs?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

How to implement **this** Google Adwords label tracking conversion using gtagjs?

```
window.google_trackConversion({
  google_conversion_id: 1053230267,
  google_conversion_label: 'oeTXCJCwzmQQu4mc9gM',
  google_conversion_value: 1.00,
  google_custom_params: window.google_tag_params
});
```

The previous code was used with Google's **conversion_async.js** In Google's **gtagjs** should be similar to this:

```
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
  'send_to': 'AW-1053230267/oeTXCJCwzmQQu4mc9gM',
  'value': 1.00
});
```

Except I don't know how to pass the "old" **google_custom_params** values. Normally this is an **object with custom keys** that gets stored in Adwords and can be used to segment audiences.